# Postfix is slow and IO hog

Tags: performance, postfix

I have an smtp-server on java which I find rather slow. Tried other smtp servers for reference and found that postfix (cpp?) and samotop (rust) are even slower.

I'm running smtp-servers on the same hardware (2core celeron, linux)

rtt between client and server is 2ms, bandwidth is 1Gbps.

testing command

```
smtp-source -d -l 5000 -m 100000 -s 15 -S bench -f spam@server.net -t spam@server.net server.net:25
```

I've set Maildir/ in postfix to avoid writing a single mailbox-file

recipient is ordinary system user (no ldap and so on)

and these options seem related to concurrency

```
default_process_limit = 1000 
in_flow_delay = 0s
local_destination_concurrency_limit = 40
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 40
```

1. With postfix I get about 2.5MBps (watching with dstat) and very
   strange disk io of 25MBps

   bottleneck is CPU (50% sys, 50% user), io utilization is close to
   full, but still 83%
2. With samotop I get 3MBps, disk io - 5MBps

   bottleneck is CPU (50% sys, 50% user), io utilization is negligible
   5%
3. with subetha I get 8MBps, disk io - 10MBps

   bottleneck is CPU (40% sys, 60% user), io utilization is negligible
   5%

Can postfix be faster? My daily load is the same as benchmark: a lot of mail coming to single address (mail archiving).